# Load PHP partial in Bootstrap HTML "Delighted" Template

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I started an app using the "*Delighted*" app template and I am trying to convert an *html partial page* to a *php partial page* and have it load when HTML on left nav is clicked. Once I changed the HTML to PHP, it stopped working and will not load. I have tried modifying the JS provided (below). 
Any thoughts?

**OLD HTML:**

```
<a href="my-accounts" data-original-title="My Accounts"> My Accounts </a>
```

**NEW HTML:**

```
<a href="my-accounts.php" data-original-title="My Accounts"> My Accounts</span>
</a>
```

**JS:**

```
function loadPage(url, container) {  
*//added this piece*  
if (url.lastIndexOf(".") > -1) {  
    urlExt = url;  
}   
*//original code*  
else {  
    urlExt = url + '.html';  
}  
//console.log(container)  
$.ajax({  
    type: "GET",  
    url: urlExt,  
    dataType: 'html',  
    cache: false,  
    success: function...etc...  
});
```

}

Comment: Elisa, why do you try to convert an HTML page? How is it not working? Is it giving you errors in your browser?

Comment: Have you checked whether the code you added actually does what it is supposed to? Make a debug output of the `urlExt` variable using `console.log` before the `$.ajax` call, and _check_ it.

Comment: Here is what shows when the My Accounts Link on the left is clicked to return the php file...  

Warning: require_once(/includes/FileMaker.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Portal-ACG/my-accounts.php on line 2

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/includes/FileMaker.php' (include_path='.:') in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Portal-ACG/my-accounts.php on line 2

Comment: Sorry, the last error was because my MAMP was not set up quite right. It is set up correctly now.

The "Delighted" template I purchased is using an Angular type of routing to show partial pages. Because the template was built to render and route HTML pages, the .php extension is not being found. I believe it is a routing error and I don't quite understand how it works. I think there is a small detail I am missing.